# How to count the number of values in a table with 2 columns as the parameter on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have 2 tables, where the values are as follow:

Table A:

```
|     Date     |     Time     |     Count     |
===============================================
|      D1      |      T1      |       0       |
|      D1      |      T2      |       0       |
|      D2      |      T1      |       0       |
|      D2      |      T2      |       0       |
```

Table B:

```
|     Date     |     Time     |     Value     |
===============================================
|      D1      |      T1      |       a       |
|      D1      |      T1      |       b       |
|      D1      |      T1      |       c       |
|      D1      |      T2      |       e       |
|      D2      |      T1      |       f       |
|      D2      |      T1      |       g       |
|      D2      |      T1      |       h       |
|      D2      |      T2      |       i       |
|      D2      |      T2      |       j       |
```

I'm trying to create a query that could count the number of `Value` from `Table B` and insert the result into the column `Count` of `Table A`

Where the result should show (on Table A):

```
|     Date     |     Time     |     Count     |
===============================================
|      D1      |      T1      |       3       |
|      D1      |      T2      |       1       |
|      D2      |      T1      |       3       |
|      D2      |      T2      |       2       |
```

I tried using normal UPDATE with the code:

```
UPDATE A
SET Count = (SELECT COUNT(Value)
             FROM B, A
             WHERE A.Date = B.Date
                   and A.Time = B.Time)
```

> However, it resulted in all Count becoming 9 instead of showing each Date and Time set its value

I couldn't create an ID for each Date and Time data, as the values of the column Date and Time will change each hours

Is there something wrong with my code or is there any other way to approach this?

Thank you in advance for any help provided

Comment: The query posted should work. Is this the exact same query you are using against your actual data?

Comment: Not exactly, I'm reducing the amount of unused columns because my actual data is very huge. However, my structure is exactly the same. I also tried to put in Group By as well, but seems that changes nothing too @GiorgosBetsos

Comment: It seems my remark was correct. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your SQL is it does not distinguish between rows - it simply updates all of them to a single calculated value. You need to join the table you're updating back to the source - which is this case is a grouped version of `tableB`.

This should do it

```
UPDATE tableA 
SET Count = b.Count
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Date, Time, COUNT(value) as Count
    FROM tableB
    GROUP BY Date,Time
) b
ON a.Date = b.Date AND a.Time=b.Time
```

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7264f/2

Comment: Is the b.Count on the second row referring to the column B.Value or is that supposed to be COUNT instead?

Comment: @ErickVanhite The code in this answer is tested and demonstrated (giving your expected result). The `b.Count` refers to the aliased table `b` lower down and is itself the result of doing `Count(Value)` from your `TableB`

Comment: Ah right, sorry took me a while to understand due to all the aliases, thank you very much it worked now

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `JOIN`. But the second table should be with the count of `[Value]` as a sub-query.

**Query**

```
update t1
set [t1].[Count] = [t2].[Count]
from [TableA] as [t1]
join (
    select [Date], [Time], count([Value]) as [Count]
    from [TableB]
    group by [Date], [Time]
) as [t2]
on [t1].[Date] = [t2].[Date]
and [t1].[Time] = [t2].[Time];
```

Answer (score 1):

The query you are using:

```
UPDATE A
SET Count = (SELECT COUNT(Value)
             FROM B, A --<-- A being used here overrides `A` of `UPDATE`
             WHERE A.Date = B.Date
                   and A.Time = B.Time)
```

uses a subquery to update `A` rows. The subquery applies `COUNT` to a list of joined rows between `A` and `B`. So, `COUNT` returns always the same value for every row of `A` that is updated.

The original query posted, i.e. the one before the edit was made in the OP, was correct:

```
UPDATE A
SET Count = (SELECT COUNT(Value)
             FROM B
             WHERE A.Date = B.Date
                   and A.Time = B.Time)
```

In this query there is a correlation between the row being updated and all rows from `B`, based on the condition:

```
A.Date = B.Date and A.Time = B.Time
```

Hence, the value returned by the subquery is dependent upon `Date` and `Time` fields of every single row being update.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a5933/1)